# Why returning pointer instead of variable itself is correct for functions with reference return type

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Consider the following example class taken from *Bjarne Stroustrup - A Tour of C++ (2nd edition)*:

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} { }
    double& operator[](int i) { return elem[i]; }
    int size() { return sz; }
private:
    double* elem;
    int sz = 0;
};
```

As far as I yet understand, in `double& operator[]` method body, `elem[i]` (which is the same as `elem + i`) has a type of pointer to double `double*`.

So, the question is: why is it correct returning **pointer to double** though method signature implies a **reference to double** (variable itself) to be returned?

Moreover, compiler throws an error if I tried returning dereferenced `*elem[i]` instead of `elem[i]`.

Comment: If you are asking about `return elem[i];`, that doesn't return a pointer. The `[]` operator derferences the pointer.

Comment: No, `elem[i]` is the same as `*(elem+i)`. The asterisk is very important.

Comment: Damn, didn't know that. Thanks a lot for explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [[expr.sub]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#1):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a
>   postfix expression. One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of type
>   “array of `T`” or a prvalue of type “pointer to `T`” and the other
>   shall be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type. The
>   result is of type “`T`”. The type “`T`” shall be a completely-defined
>   object type. **The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to
>   `*((E1)+(E2))`,** except that in the case of an array operand, the
>   result is an lvalue if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue
>   otherwise. The expression `E1` is sequenced before the expression
>   `E2`.

Here, `elem` is of type `double*`, and `i` is of type `int`.  `elem[i]` is by definition equivalent to `*(elem + i)`, which is an lvalue of type `double`.  `*elem[i]` attempts to dereference a `double`, which is ill-formed.